# the format of the input string is incorrect c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I need help, I'm getting error: the format of the input string is incorrect. Thanks in advance.

the line that been selected in error is first line

```
var getus = await _instaApi.GetUserAsync(listBox1.Items[s].ToString());
                           var userid = getus.Value.Pk;
                            var FollowResult = await _instaApi.FollowUserAsync(long.Parse(userid));
                            if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
                            {
                                var userFeed = await _instaApi.GetUserMediaAsync(listBox1.Items[s].ToString(), 1);
                                if (userFeed.Succeeded)
                                {
                                    foreach (var media in userFeed.Value.Take(1))
                                    {
                                        var likeResult = await _instaApi.LikeMediaAsync(media.InstaIdentifier);
                                        var postResult = await _instaApi.CommentMediaAsync(media.InstaIdentifier, textBox1.Text);

                                    }

                                }
                            }
```

example of string value is "username".

Comment: You should provide the exact text of the error.  Also, the error says the format of the input string is incorrect and you haven't provided the input string.

Comment: Which operation produces the error?  What is the string value?  What are you trying to convert it to?

Comment: @ilyas: Be more specific.  When you step through the code in your debugger, on exactly what line is the error thrown?  (It seems much more likely to be on that `long.Parse()` operation, for example.)  And what are the specific values of the variables?  What is the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: i wrote in my question tht error thrown on first line from code i shared here 
and also the example of string value is "username".

Comment: Read the stack trace.